# x2go resolution from windows client

Tags: linux, ssh, nomachine-nx

I'm happily using x2go to connect to a remote Ubuntu Server 16.04 with XFCE installed from my local pc with a local resolution of 1920x1080 on a HiDPI screen (13''). If I run the x2go client from a virtualized Linux (Linux Mint 18.03 with XFCE), everything works well and I can see a really sharp image of the remote desktop. Problem is, when I try to connect directly from Windows 10 the image is blurred and the resolution is wrong. I tried to play around with the x2go client settings but no way, the image is always terrible. I also tried to use PyHoca and different X-servers but the result is the same.

Is it a well-known problem? Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15):

I had a very similar problem: A Dell laptop with an Nvidia graphics card, having a resolution of the built-in flat panel of 1280x800. I connected this to an external screen with HDMI with a resolution of 1920x1080. However, X2Go seemed to pick up the resolution of the built-in screen instead of the actual screen, making everything seem blurry (interpolating 1280x800 to 1920x1080).

This is what fixed it for me: Navigate to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\X2GoClient\VcXSrv\` directory in Explorer. Select the `vcxsrv.exe` file and right-click it, choosing Properties from the popup menu. Go to the Compatibility tab, and in the Settings section there, select the option "Override high DPI scaling behavior. Scaling performed by:" and then select "Application" in the combo-box below.

Restart the X2Go Client to have its X server start with this new setting.

Comment: This worked for my screen but it resulted in slower frame refreshing, if I move the cursor around or scroll it repaints slow enough to notice now.  But it is much more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This fix also solved X2Go Windows Client crashes in my setup.

I have basically the same scenario: connecting from a high DPI Windows laptop to KDE on Debian, in my case for Desktop Sharing. The client would connect okay, but display only a portion of the remote host's screen.

Keyboard shortcuts would not scroll the client window.

Any attempt to show more (maximize, go full screen, click-and-drag client window border) would seem to work for a second, then crash.

The Compatibility scaling change fixed the instability - no more crashes, yay! - but did lead to slow repaints as noted by Algeboy.

Upgrading to a newer version of VcXsrv also did not resolve the crashes - Compatibility change still required, but screen repaints are quicker.

To upgrade, download and install [the latest VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) in its own directory. Using Explorer or whathaveyou, apply the HiDPI setting to vcxsrv,exe.

Start x2go client but don't start a session. Click Options, Settings, then X.Org Server settings tab. Select "use custom x server". Point to the newly installed vcxsrv.exe  and click okay. Restart the x2go client.

This apparently takes the version from 1.20.6.0 supplied by x2go to 1.20.14.0 (2022-04).

Screen refreshes are quicker if I minimize all applications on the host, allowing it to repaint the desktop, then restore whatever I want to work on.