# Cannot run X2go client anymore

Tags: linux, ssh, access-denied, x2go

I was having an issue wit accessing to X2Go Client and I Have tried to follow the instructions I have found here ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48091637/x2go-resolution-from-windows-client#:~:text=Start%20x2go%20client%20but%20don%27t%20start%20a%20session.,vcxsrv.exe%20and%20click%20okay.%20Restart%20the%20x2go%20client.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48091637/x2go-resolution-from-windows-client#:%7E:text=Start%20x2go%20client%20but%20don%27t%20start%20a%20session.,vcxsrv.exe%20and%20click%20okay.%20Restart%20the%20x2go%20client.)) , specifically this latter one:

*Start x2go client but don't start a session. Click Options, Settings, then X.Org Server settings tab. Select "use custom x server". Point to the newly installed vcxsrv.exe and click okay. Restart the x2go client*

Now I am struggling with the access since I am getting the following message

[image]

Any clue to solve this? I am using the version installed from here https://x2go-client.software.informer.com/download/#downloading on Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. My problem was I did not have the latest [VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/). When I installed the VcXsrv, it worked.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Actually I installed that server too but this did not fix the problem. I'll give a try a again